# How many ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of nonnegative integers are there such that $abcd = 288$?

Tags: combinatorics

I know how to do $a+b+c+d=288$, but I don't have any clue how to get started if it is multiplication.

Comment: $288 = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3$. How many ways to distribute those factors?

Comment: This very question was asked and answered just a few days ago: see the last entry under Related on the right

Comment: Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce it to a sum problem using prime factorization.

It's clear that $a,b,c,d$ must be nonzero, hence, since they are required to be nonnegative integers, they must be positive integers.

Noting that $288=2^53^2$, it follows that each of $a,b,c,d$ has a unique representation in the form $2^x3^y$, where $x,y$ are nonnegative integers.

Thus, letting
\begin{align*}
a = 2^{x_1}3^{y_1}\\[4pt]
b = 2^{x_2}3^{y_2}\\[4pt]
c = 2^{x_3}3^{y_3}\\[4pt]
d = 2^{x_4}3^{y_4}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
we get a one-to-one correspondence between solutions to the equation $$abcd=288$$
in positive integers $a,b,c,d$, and solutions to the system 
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4&=5\tag{eq1}\\[4pt]
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4&=2\tag{eq2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
in nonnegative integers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$.

Using the stars-and-bars formula, $(\text{eq}1)$ has
$$\binom{5 + 4 - 1}{4-1}=\binom{8}{3}=56$$
solutions, and $(\text{eq}2)$ has
$$\binom{2 + 4 - 1}{4-1}=\binom{5}{3}=10$$
solutions.

Hence the number of solutions to the system is$$(56)(10) = 560$$
which is therefore also the number of solutions to the original equation.